# WebMethod not getting fired when called using AngularJS request

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs

WebMethod not getting fired when called using AngularJS request

Even when using 
     [WebMethod]
     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

it is giving me 500 internal server error as the method is not getting fired what should i do to enter the webmethod or what i have done wrong ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

  var app = angular.module("ActionListApp", []);

     app.factory("Actions", function () {
         var serviceObj = {};
         serviceObj.AddAction = function ($http, $scope, $filter) {
             debugger;
             var req = {
                 method: 'POST',
                 url: 'ActionList.aspx/AddAction',
                 data: {
                     strAction: $scope.mdlAction, intCategory: $scope.mdlCategory, intAsssignedTo: $scope.mdlAssignedTo

                     }
             }
             $http(req).success(function (data) {
                 result = angular.fromJson(data.d);
                 alert('success');
                 //$scope.EventsList = result.Events;
                 //$scope.Pages = result.Pages;
             }).error(function (data) {
                 alert('error');
                 console.log('error: Could not add the student');
             });

         };
         return serviceObj;
     });

     app.controller("ActionController", function ($http, $scope, $filter, 
 Actions) {

         $scope.ctrAddAction = function () {
             debugger;
             $scope.dtDueDate = 
 document.getElementById('dtDueDate').value;
             Actions.AddAction($http, $scope, $filter);
         };
     });
</script>
```

this is my aspx.cs code :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static string AddAction(String strAction, int intCategory, int 
 intAssignedTo)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        dynamic json = new JObject();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds=obj.AddAction(strAction, intCategory, intAssignedTo);
        json.action = (JArray)JToken.FromObject(ds.Tables[0]);
        return json.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dynamic d = new JObject();
        d.status = "error";
        d.errormsg = ex.Message;
        d.stack = ex.StackTrace;
        return d.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with other JS request call?
Check the request type, maybe it is an OPTION type and this may be the reason of the internal server error (500).

Comment: Tried that but nope that is not the solution